# files & directories are not share on remote server with 777 permission using sshfs

Tags: permissions, automounting, sshfs

I am successfully mount the remote directories on my local directories, I have to created folder and files with 777 permission so others can able to access this files so that's why I used umask=000 option during mount process. But problem is these newly created folder and files not created with 777 permission on remote server(NFS Server) IT create with 775 permission.

I have two servers with following user.

1. NFS Server 
   nfs2
   root
2. NFS clinet
   root
   stag

Following is the export entry on NFS server

```
/home/nfs2/mnt *(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
```

Following command I used to mount directories...

```
sshfs -o uid=1005,gid=1005,umask=000 nfs2@xxx.xxx.x.xx:/home/nfs2/mnt /home/stag/mount_point -o allow_other
```

After apply above command remote directory successfully mounted on /home/stag/mount_point with 777 permission.

Now I am creating directory using stag user.

```
**stag@ubuntu:~/mount_point$ mkdir test
stag@ubuntu:~/mount_point$ ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 1 stag stag 4096 Mar  5 14:24 test**
```

And it is created with 777 permission what I want, So on NFS client side I don't have any issue.

Now I checking on NFS server in /home/nfs2/mnt directory.

```
**root@192:/home/nfs2/mnt# ls -l
total 4 
drwxrwxr-x 2 nfs2 nfs2 4096 Mar  5 14:24 test**
```

As you see on NFS server test directory was created with 775 permission which did not I want, I want to create test directory with 777 permission.

I did everything to resolve this issue,

I set umask 000 into .bashrc file on NFS server but then also this issue not resolved.

I found following link in which one guy say I have apply patch for sshfs-fush to resolve the permission issue on server side and after that I have to used **remote_umask and remote_fmask** during mount process.

```
**http://andre.frimberger.de/index.php/linux/sshfs-fix-for-wrong-file-permissions-on-server/comment-page-1/#comment-211337**
```

But I don't know How to apply this patch.

Any know how to resolve this problem then please help me.

Thanks